What are some good financial metrics to use while purchasing index funds?
I am a beginner to investing. I was wondering if someone could list the important financial metrics to understand to analyze index funds? I checked Yahoo Finance, and I see some metrics such as YTD return, Expense Ratio, etc. Are these metrics enough?


IMHO, you are over thinking this.  Choose Fidelity, Vanguard, or Schwab and use their trackers.  Then find ways to earn extra money to sock away in these funds.


Low fees.

Which index they are tracking, of course. Recommended mixes have been discussed in earlier answers.

Low fees.

Historical performance vs. the index they are tracking.

Low fees.

A provider you trust.

Low fees.

Convenient access.

Low fees.



It's also important that the amount of money the provider charges you for running the tracker fund is not too high... :-)

What about Low Fees?  :)   In all seriousness, for a beginner - the desire to hold for a long time or forever. The nice thing about a index that covers a major sector is you are effectively betting on America (assuming US).

Once you decide which index you want to invest in, then you have to pick the exact fund.
The best thing about an index fund is that the fund management company doesn't have to use a lot of resources to decide what to do with any money coming into the fund, or which shares to sell if they have to.  They just use the inflows and outflows to make their actual investments better track the index they are supposed to match.
Therefore look at the fees charged by the fund. It will never be zero. They still have some expense: accountants, auditors, computers, etc.
Once you have the ones with the lowest fees, pick the ones that does a better job tracking the index, and is with a company you trust.
Some people will go with a company that they already have investments with, because it is easy to check the balances, and you can move money easier. Others don't want to have all their investment with one fund management company.

First, decide which index to invest in. In my opinion, metrics such as YTD return should be considered at this step (or not at all).
Second, pick a fund/ETF that tracks this index or a similar index. Things to consider:

Expense ratio. The lower the better.
Asset Under Management (AUM) in dollar terms. Make sure this is not too low. Otherwise, the ETF has a high risk of liquidation.
Bid/ask spread. The lower the better. The higher this is, effectively you pay more for purchasing and selling this ETF.
Fund management and fund custodian. If you invest in multiple ETFs, I believe it's better to diversify the companies behind fund management and custody, in case one of the companies goes wrong (e.g., scandal). You can find out the custodian in the document of the fund. For example, the statement of additional information of VTI says: "Custodians. JPMorgan Chase Bank, N.A..."
If you are using a broker that charges commissions differently based on which ETF you are trading, then it's better to also take that into account.

